# Elements of the Galois Group on the Convex Hull of the Roots of a Polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, galois-theory

I'm curious about the convex hull of roots of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ and how elements of a Galois group affect the geometry of the complex plane. It seems like if $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with splitting field $E$ and if $\text{Conv}(\beta) \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the convex hull of the root set $\beta$ of $p$, then any element $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ will preserve that convex hull, i.e.
$$ \text{Conv}(\beta) = \sigma(\text{Conv}(\beta)). $$
For example with $f(x) = (x^2 - 2)(x^2 + 1)$, we get complex conjugation as one element of the Galois group. Even though this element is really an automorphism of the splitting field which sends $i \mapsto -i$, there's a natural extension to a map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$: complex conjugation. My first question then is

1. Is there always an extension $\sigma':\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ of $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\sigma'|_E = \sigma$?

If there is, I'd like to think about the affects of the map $\sigma'$ on the complex plane. With the complex conjugation example, it's not super interesting. But maybe on more complicated elements of more complicated Galois groups, the affects on the complex plane (or even just the interior of the convex hull of the roots of the polynomial) are interesting. For example, (2.) does $\sigma'$ always preserve the interior of the convex hull, as in complex conjugation?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't $\sigma$ just permute the roots, so in the end the convex hull won't change.
For 1. see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93124/automorphisms-of-mathbbc#:~:text=Yes%2C%20any%20automorphism%20of%20%C2%AF,pair%20of%20algebraically%20closed%20fields.

Comment: Thank you @Kolja, that answers 1. You're right that the convex hull won't change because $\sigma$ permutes the roots, but I'm particularly curious about the interior of the convex hull. As in, if $z \in$ the interior of $\text{Conv}(\beta) \subset \mathbb{C}$, then is $\sigma'(z) \in$ the interior of $\text{Conv}(\beta)$? For the Galois group of the $f(x)$ example in my original post, this seems to be true (the convex hull is a square, and the Galois group is $D_4$ acting naturally on it). But it's not clear whether this is always true. I suspect not, but I don't know